# Why are statistics slower to build on clustered columnstore?

Tags: sql-server, statistics, columnstore

Building statistics on a clustered columnstore table always seems to read the whole table, even if I ask for a small sample. Why is this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sampled statistics on a heap or b-tree use `TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM`. This algorithm employs an [allocation-ordered scan](http://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/allocation-order-scans) and chooses pages from the scan to sample. All rows on the selected pages contribute to the statistics histogram. You can find details of the selection process in my answer to [Strange behaviour with sample sizes for statistics updates](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/180461/1192).

Clustered columnstore implements `TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM` differently. There are two separate sampling strategies:

The **first algorithm** is only used when selecting rows for the *primary dictionary* build phase of a columnstore index creation (highlighted in the clustered columnstore build plan below).

[image: Primary dictionary build]

The implementation is optimized for performance but gives up some accuracy. It uses cluster sampling similar in concept to the method for heaps and b-trees: A set of row groups is randomly selected, followed by a random sample of rows within each selected group. The number of rows and row groups selected is derived from the sampling percentage. Row groups that are not selected in the initial step are not read from disk.

The primary dictionary build phase can be skipped in SQL Server 2019 or later by enabling global trace flag 11611.

The **second algorithm** is always used for statistics builds. It uses truly random row-level sampling but has a higher I/O and CPU cost. It scans *all segments* for a column and randomly selects a subset of rows. This can produce more accurate histograms than for b-trees and heaps, which only sample whole pages.

The final statistics object will reflect the desired sampling rate. The implementation makes this more difficult to see than with heaps or b-trees because all segments are read during the process.